# Does discarding cards face down affect the distribution of the remaining cards?

Tags: probability, card-games

You have a deck of $N$ cards, $Y$ of which are labelled "A". $N$ and $Y$ are known.

Does discarding $n$ cards face down from the top of the deck affect the probability that the next card drawn is labelled "A"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have $N=$3 cards, with $Y=2$ being labelled "A". You then discard $n=$2 cars.
Now the last card has $67$% chance of being labelled "A", but the remaining set of 1 cards cannot contain 2 cards with "A" on it.

So the $67$% remains the same while the distribution of number of "A" cards changes.

Comment: Thank you. This is precisely what I have been saying all along.

Comment: Out of curiosity, your answer holds true even for $N = 33$, $Y = 7$ and $n = 5$, right?

Comment: Specify what you mean by "distribution of cards".

Comment: I mean the probability that the next card drawn will be labelled "A".

Distribution was probably a poor choice of wording.

Comment: Okay, then notice that "the next card" is the same as if you had just picked the sixth card instead of the first card in the beginning.